# What does "with commendation in" mean?

Tags: meaning

> He received a diploma with commendation in Computer Science from XX
>   School.

Does "with commendation in" just a fancy word to say "diploma for Computer Science", or is there any special meaning to this? The dictionary meaning for "commendation" is compliment/award, and It seems awkward to interpret "commendation" as an award. A diploma with award in Computer Science? I don't think so... What does "with commendation in" mean?

Comment: "With commendation" is awarded for scoring a certain per centage higher than ordinarily required for a mere passing grade. Are you from the US, the UK or elsewhere?

Comment: I'd guess it's an attempt to translate [*cum laude*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cum%20laude).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're parsing it wrong.

It's not

> a diploma (with commendation in computer science),

it's

> (a diploma with commendation) in computer science.

And a *diploma with commendation* means that you have performed at a higher level than would be needed for an ordinary diploma. Exactly what level that is, and what percentage of graduates get it depends on the school.